# How can I get the sum of integers in a text file with c++?

Tags: c++, loops, sum, text-files, fstream

I apologize if this is a simple question, I'm teaching myself c++ and can't seem to find the solution I'm looking for to this one anywhere.

Say I have a text file with data organized like this:

10 - sample 1

20 - sample 2

30 - sample 3

40 - sample 4

Is there a way I can get the numbers from each line and store their sum in a variable? Or am I approaching this incorrectly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Break the task into smaller ones. Each of them is already answered.

Comment: @Blake Greene: You can check my answer below, and please [*have a look at this page*](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to include the `<fstream>` in your header file list.

Then:

1- Open your file.
2- Read it line after another.
3- Sum up the numbers.
4- Print the total.

You will need to read about files to fully understand how it works

```
int main()
{
        fstream MyFile;  // declare a file

        MyFile.open("c:\\temp\\Numbers.txt", ios::in); // open the file

        int sum = 0;
        string line;


        while (getline(MyFile, line))  //reading a line from the file while possible
        {
            sum = sum + stoi(line);    // convert string to number and add it to the sum
        }

        MyFile.close();   // closing the file

        cout << "sum is: " << sum;  // print the sum

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create the file with `std::ifstream MyFile("c:\\temp\\Numters.txt");` That's what the constructor is for. And don't bother to close it; that's what the destructor is for.

Comment: @Pete Becker: I thought it is a good idea for a beginner to know about `open` and `close` and other file concepts. They will get to constructors and destructors some point in future, and they will appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I think they should learn and start using RAII as soon as possible, but regardless of that, it would be better to actually check if that file is open ;)...

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the right idea just couldn't get to the solution for the life of me! I tried to find the answer on here but none of them seemed to clue me in. Appreciate the help:)